# Change notification email subject - Nagios

Tags: 12.04, system, administration, administrator, nagios3

Anyone can give an idea about, how can I change my Nagios email alert subject? I have google for sometime and every result says to change the command(notify-host-by-email) definition in commands.cfg file. But the command line consists of only email body part. I am new to Nagios and please advice me where should I look for changing email alert subject ?
Thanks in advance. Please let me know if need any information related to this.

Comment: What is it now, and what do you want to change it to?

Comment: This how it is getting now(example) -  ** PROBLEM Service Alert:  <Server host name>/Total Processes is WARNING **. And I want to change it to something customized one, like,  "Total process is getting increase, please have a look". :)